# Role Based Routing in core ui react

Tags: reactjs

I have downloaded react admin dashboard from core ui, I need to implement role based routing. e.g. User A can only access Home A, Page A, Page B, Page C and user B can only access Home B, Page B, Page D, Page E.

How can i go about it using selector and role based routing?

Route.js

```
    const routes = [
      { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home' },
      { path: '/PageA', name: 'Page A', element: Dashboard },
      { path: '/PageB', name: 'Page B', element: Colors, exact: true },
      { path: '/PageC', name: 'Page C', element: Colors },
      { path: '/PageD', name: 'Page D', element: Typography },
      { path: '/PageE', name: 'Page E', element: Cards, exact: true },
    ]
```

AppContent.js

```
    import routes from '../routes'
    const AppContent = () => {
      return (
        <CContainer className="px-4" lg>
          <Suspense fallback={<CSpinner color="primary" />}>
            <Routes>
              {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                return (
                  route.element && (
                    <Route
                      key={idx}
                      path={route.path}
                      exact={route.exact}
                      name={route.name}
                      element={<route.element />}
                    />
                  )
                )
              })}
              <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="login" replace />} />
            </Routes>
          </Suspense>
        </CContainer>
      )
    }
```

I have tried passing in the user selector in Routes.js but i don't know how to change AppContent.js for the change.

Route.js

```
    const routes = (user) => [
    {
        path: 'dash',
        element: user?.UserType === 'SPMR' ? 'redirect to home page but don't know how' : <Navigate to='/login' />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <HomeA /> },
          { path: 'pagea', element: <PageA/> },
          { path: 'pageb', element: <PageB /> },
          { path: 'pagec', element: <PageC/> },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

Comment: You seem to seek for "protected routes" (you may google the term for details). One way to implement it would be to put together `<ProtectedRoute />` component that wraps Router's `<Route />` component and contains all the logic required to decide whether the user is authorized to access a particular page/route and return the `<Route />` with respective props or redirect to login page, otherwise.

Comment: Hi Yevhen Horbunkov, as I'm relatively new to react, do you have codes on your explanation? Thank you.

Comment: The concept is fairly trivial. Hopefully, I managed to deliver the key point for you to grasp it. If you seek code examples, do a bit more research on "protected routes" over here or in Google - I'm sure, you'll find tons of these.